# AWS RDS: mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'databasetest.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)")

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, boto

I have this code below to connect to a rds instance.

But Im having this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'databaseTest.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)")
```

Do you see anything wrong with the code?

```
import boto.rds
import MySQLdb

instanceID = "databaseTest"
username = "root"
password = "pass"
getDBEndpoint = conn.get_all_dbinstances(instance_id=instanceID)[0].endpoint
dbEndpoint = getDBEndpoint[0]

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=dbEndpoint,user=username,passwd=password, db = dbName, port = 3306)
```

I created the db instance like this:

```
db = conn.create_dbinstance(instanceID,dbSize,instanceType, username, password, port = instancePort, engine=dbEngine, db_name = dbName)
```

Comment: How are your DBSecurityGroups configured?  Are you authorized to access the DB from your host?

Comment: The instance security group is the default security group!

Comment: But what are the security groups for your RDS instance?  The default behavior is to not allow any access.  You have to explicitly enable access by CIDR or by EC2 security group.

Comment: Im starting learning about RDS, and I think Im a bit confuse about how it works. We need to start an ec2 instance to use RDS? And than use that instance to connect to RDS instance?

Comment: Your RDS instance is just a MySQL database server.  You can use it just like any other MySQL server.  However, you need to use Security Groups in RDS to determine who can actually access the server.  By default, no one can.  You can either add a rule to your Security Group to whitelist a particular IP address by CIDR or, if you are accessing it from an EC2 instance, you can allow access via the EC2 security group.

Comment: Thank you really for your comment, now Im understanding better how rds works!